# Regex expression for searching spaced/broken words in OCR PDFs (goo d ni g ht)

Tags: regex, pdf, ocr, space

I need searching lots of OCR PDFs. I realized the words and sentences are perfect visually, but if I copy an paste the content, there are spaces which shouldn't be there!

I can see in the text: `good night`

If I copy and paste somewhere: `goo d ni g ht`

I would appreciate advices to handle this situation through a Regex expression considering:

a) The simple example for short words as `\bgood night\b` for `goo d ni g ht`

b) When there is line break in the sentence. I mean, the Regex expression isn't able to search from one line to another in the PDF even the paragraph is the same. In looking for 
`\bthe sun set and the night comes\b` , but the PDF content is like that when pasted:

line 1: `t he sun set an d th e`

line 2: `nig ht co m es`

Many thanks,
Cadu

Comment: How do you plan to perform the replacement?

Comment: Actually, I am looking for a expression to ignore "spaces" between words and sentences, since I am searching the exact sentence \bthe sun set and the night comes\b considering those crazy spaces could exist anywhere. I am not concerned with replacement, but just to find if the words/sentences exist in the text/PDF. Thanks!

Comment: can you provide a sample file (raw) not copy paste ?

Comment: Would it suffice to remove *all* spaces in both the text extracted from the PDf and your search string?

Comment: "remove all spaces in both the text extracted from the PDf and your search string". => I think it would work. My point is that I just need to search for \bgood night\b but the words have spaces because the OCR => goo d ni g ht . I just need to add (if this exist in Regex) a function that should return the sequence of characters "good night" even if there is spaces (1 or more) or not between the characters. So the expression should find: goo d ni g ht , good night, goodnight. Thanks!

Comment: which OCR software/engine was used to do the OCR? Using another OCR software might change things.

Comment: Actually it happens with ocr but even journal articles, pdf printed from web etc. Have these crazy spacing sometimes. So, my point is to find a expression which matches all the sequence of characters despite having space or not between them... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This random occurence of spaces in the middle of words can happen in PDF.
The reason behind it is the complex format that PDF actually is.
You see, a PDF document is actually a container of instructions for rendering the text in a viewer.

Imagine instructions like:

- go to position 50, 50.
- draw the character 'G'
- go to position 56, 50.
- draw the character 'O'
- etc

Whenever you select something in a viewer (for instance Adobe), the program has to figure out what content overlaps with your selection (already this is not an easy problem). If it's text, it then needs to decide where to add spaces and line-breaks. Different viewers (or software) might use different metrics for this. A typical one for instance is "insert a space if two characters are further apart than the width of the space character in the same font"

The point is, getting text out of a PDF document is always kind of guesswork. And if you add the fact that it's an OCR PDF, you are adding a further layer of difficulties.